# JS - converting string from data-attribute into object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like:

```
<span class="someClass" id="skAdmin" data-options='{
   "elmsList" : {
      "#skAdmin" : {
         "action" : "replace",
         "replaceWith" : "<input class=\"form-control\">"
         }
      }
   }'>Name</span>
```

Now (when i make a click on this *span*) I need to replace this element (*span*) by element in data-options (*input*). And at the same time i need to add all *span* attributes to *input* element, but *input* is just a text (not an object). How can I convert this to object?

Comment: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)!

Comment: @ComFreek you don't need to a jQuery will have already done that. In memory this data-attribute will already be an object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan jQuery? JSON.parse() is not jQuery. See Sirko's answer.

Comment: @ComFreek obviously. However the OP tagged this question as jQuery  and as such `JSON.parse` seems redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see. I didn't know that jQuery would automatically parse JSON. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to retrieve an object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse( document.querySelector( '#skAdmin' ).dataset.options );

// or

var obj = JSON.parse( document.getElementById( 'skAdmin' ).dataset.options );
```

**Edit**

As the comments note, if you are already using jQuery, [all `data-*` attributes will already be parsed into jQuery's `data` object](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5). So you can access it by just using:

```
var obj = $( '#skAdmin' ).data( 'options' );
```

Comment: jQuery also exposes a [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method should all the browsers you target not support `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: `querySelector` is unnecessary, use `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: or `var obj = $('#skAdmin').data('options');`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to parse this value as jQuery will have already done this for you when it stored it in it's in-memory cache. Therefore you can access it like an object:

```
$('.someClass').click(function() {
    var replaceWith = $(this).data('options').elmsList['#skAdmin'].replaceWith;
    $(this).replaceWith(replaceWith)
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Ak8LT/)